# Webservice args types automatic validation

Tags: 7, services

It's a Drupal 7 with Webservices module, and there is a service with something like this (example):

```
'create-product' => array(
  'operations' => array(
    'create' => array(
      'help' => t('Add Product'),
      'file' => array(
        'type' => 'endpoints.inc',
        'module' => 'custommodule',
        'name' => 'custommodule',
      ),
        'callback' => 'custommodule_create_product',
        'args' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'appID',
                'type' => 'int',
                'description' => t("App ID"),
                'source' => array('data' => 'appID'),
                'optional' => FALSE
            ),
            ...
```

Okay, so the type here is "int". Is it possible to make Drupal return some error automatically, if it's not an int that is being sent as appID.
Like if it's a string being sent, then it will throw an error.
I can't make it work.
Why else is there a "type" key-value?

Comment: What does the service return if you don't send an `int`?

Comment: it returns whatever I want it to return... I want a way to trigger an exception, if it's even possible... (this is about INCOMING data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it appears Services doesn't validate the incoming data based on the `type`, you can use an `access callback` to build your own validation.

Add something like this to your Service Resource definition:

```
// ...
'access callback' => '_example_resource_access',
'access callback file' => array(
  'type' => 'inc',
  'module' => 'example',
  'name' => 'example.resource-access',
),
'access arguments' => array('foo bar'),
'access arguments append' => TRUE,
// ...
```

Then create a file called `example.resource-access.inc` with a function like this:

```
function _example_resource_access($op, $args = array()) {    
  if ($op == 'foo bar' && !is_numeric($args[0])) {
    return services_error(t('That is not an integer.'), 406);
  }    
  return TRUE;    
}
```

Note, `$args[0]` will likely come in as a string representing an integer, so using `is_numeric()` should be accurate, unless you specifically use `(int)` to cast `$args[0]` beforehand, then you can run it through `is_int()` for validation instead.

Comment: Thats what I did